# MySQL performance JSON functions

Tags: mysql

We faced with unpredictable duration of executing our code. The same query can take less than a second, or more than a minute. It looks like our attempt to use MySQL JSON_ functions probably was not a good idea.

```
select p.pk,
   p.name,
   ... /* fields from primary table */
   (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(CODE)
    FROM (SELECT region.region_pk AS CODE
          FROM program_region region
          WHERE region.program_pk = p.pk) AS a)
                                                   AS region_codes,
   (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(CODE)
    FROM (SELECT affiliate.affiliate_pk AS CODE
          FROM program_affiliate affiliate
          WHERE affiliate.program_pk = p.pk) AS a) AS affiliate_codes,
   (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(user_id)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
          FROM (SELECT role.user_id
                FROM program_role role
                WHERE role.program_pk = p.pk
                UNION ALL
                SELECT p.created_by) AS us) AS a)  AS user_ids 
from program p;
```

Structure:

**program**:

```
pk bigint, 
name varchar ...
```

**program_affiliate and other child tables**

```
pk bigint, 
program_pk bigint /* FK with index */ 
code varchar(20) 
...
```

We checked another queries works as usual but only new ones has these issues.

Does anybody else faced with performance  issues with JSON functions before? Any recommendations?

Comment: If you are using JSON Arrays why are you using MySQL and not MongoDB ? Just curious.

Comment: The short answer is something to do with Indexing and perhaps partitioning.  What happens when you Explain Analyze (THE SELECT) ?  Does it give different results on different scans?

Comment: "our attempt to use MySQL JSON_ functions probably was not a good idea." That's my general opinion about JSON in SQL.

Comment: That is sort of what I was getting at with my comment as well.  I suspect a legacy situation inherent with the design.

Comment: Well, you're using correlated queries in the select-list, which is a known performance liability even if you're not using JSON. (I assume `p` is an alias for your outer query on `main_data`, because `p` isn't defined anywhere else in the query.)

Comment: The query does not look like a valid query. What are `a.id` and `a.name` referring to? Did you simplify the query? To help with the performance, you should show the table create definitions and the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: @easleyfixed, we used MySQL as RDBMS, but we have a couple cases when JSON could be more convenient and I think that's too expensive to add another DB instance for a couple cases.

Comment: If its just a few cases, then do as you have been, but if you need that better performance, JSON is handled much more efficiently in MongoDB from my understanding.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM (SELECT role.user_id ....)`. seems less efficient than  `SELECT DISTINCT role.user_id....`.  ?

Comment: Try to redesign the schema and rewrite the code _without_ subqueries (use `JOIN` if possible) and _without_ `JSON` (use rows and columns).

Comment: What is the goal behind the query?  Please provide a short set of data and the desired output.